# AD Sync strange behavior

Tags: user-profile-service, fim

Sync is running fine. It updates and adds users.

However, some of the employees in the same OU are not being added when FIM runs. Any reason for this?

Comment: I just sat with the Network Admin guy and checked profile that come over to SP and profiles that did not make it to SP in AD. They are in same OU and same exact setup. Can anyone please shed some light on this? I would truly appreciated it. I am on a dead line as I have 300 new users and only 26 users made it SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Sync Configuration has a bug. All I had to do is uncheck the OU and Re-check the OU and then I started syncying everyone else.